# My design is practically screaming for OOP. Should I change my design or change my programming language?

Tags: c++, c, oop, abstraction

I'm writing a hobby project wherein I write to .wav files. I decided that the best way to do this is to create a single C file with a bunch of routines to initialize and manipulate a struct with metadata about the wave file that the user should never manually manipulate, but should instead pass a pointer to routines. An example of how using this interface would look like is the following:

```
/* wave_new_file() implicitly allocates memory for the struct */
Wavefile *outputWave = wave_new_file("out.wav", WAVE_mono);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_RANDOM_SAMPLES; i++)
    wave_write(outputWave, rand());

wave_close(outputWave);
```

I realize that the rest of my design could potentially be simplified in the long-run by using an OOP approach, such as in the following pseudo-C++ (since I'm not actually familiar with C++; more on that later):

```
Wavefile *outputWave = new Wavefile("out.wav", WAVE_mono);

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RANDOM_SAMPLES; i++)
    outputWave->write(rand());

outputWave->close(); /* Or delete perhaps? */
```

The problem with this is that: the rest of my project is written in C99; and I don't actually know C++ (I learned OOP from Python, but am now concentrating on programming in C).

Should I: refactor my design to not rely heavily on OOP principals or should I take the time and learn C++ and migrate my entire program to C++? It's not a large program and it *is* just a hobby project (which explains my reinventing the wheel by making my own .wav writing module). Or should I continue with my pseudo-object-oriented design I currently find myself writing?

Comment: Learn C++, it's awesome. And you can use your previously written C code too.

Comment: The answer lies in how much time you have on hand. If you have the time, refactor!

Comment: @MarceloCantos I was asking you! Is it even worth it?

Comment: Hobby projects should be all about experimentation and learning. Keep your C code and try writing it in C++. See if it's better, what you like/dislike about both implementations, and learn from the experience!

Comment: @eddieantonio: You weren't asking if the C++ version is simpler; you were stating it as a fact. In any event, see my answer.

Comment: C++ is a huge language which takes time to learn. If you're serious and interested, go for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it really comes down to your ultimate goals.  If you are purely doing this as a hobby and you are developing this for your own use, then you might be happy enough to stick with what you are doing.  However, if you are looking not just for a solution but a good solution to a problem, looking for something new, or doing this as preparation for searching for a job, I would move forward with more heavily investing yourself into either C++ or potentially a completely different language like Java.

Summary in code:

```
 if(DESIRE_SHORT_TERM_PROJECT_COMPLETION){
      stickWithC = true;
 }else if(DESIRE_KNOWLEDGE_AND_EXPERIENCE_AND_PLAN_TO_DEVELOP_LONG_TERM){
      stickWithC = false;
 }
```

Comment: I'm going the experience route. C++, here I come.

Comment: Woot!  I find I am most entertained when learning new things, so have at it and have fun!

Answer (score 2):

In what way is the C++ version simpler?

Not that I'm disagreeing with the idea of using C++. I think you'll benefit from a light sprinkling of C++ idioms such as using smart pointers to manage the lifecycle of your Wavefile objects, but this doesn't suggest that you need to abandon your current design entirely.

Another benefit of C++ is that it provides stronger type-safety, even if your code remains C-conformant.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it C. If you need OOP, use function pointers. It's quite common practice in Linux kernel.

Comment: +1 I don't like those anon-y-mouse down voters. It's quite a sensible approach if you're staying with C. Why not do your *next* project in C++? Always useful to finish something.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Would the benefits of rewriting it outweigh the inconvenience of rewriting it? If so, do it. Without knowing more about your project, this is the best answer I can give.

On the other hand, since this is a hobby project, if you're looking for an excuse to rewrite it, or bust out some c++, even if it's technically not the best use of your time, then go for it, **especially** if you're interested in learning more about C++. If you're looking for an excuse to keep writing in C, then do that!